# Website Deep Products links not indexing In Google

Tags: indexing, google-search-console

I am working on one website, I have set all the required this for seo and looks all things are fine.

►But from long time, I have seen that deep product links are not going to index in Google as well some of the catagory pages.

Here is the site https://www.tradohub.com

What should I do for Google to index my web site? if someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Please check it in google or read it here : https://blog.kissmetrics.com/get-google-to-index/

Answer (score 0):

You have a canonical tag issue with your internal pages.

Let's take this page as an example...

https://www.tradohub.com/product-detail/raw-cashew-nuts

Reading the source code you have a canonical of...

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.tradohub.com/" />
```

This tells search engines the page is a copy of the home page URL so will most likely not get indexed.

The canonical should be...

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.tradohub.com/product-detail/raw-cashew-nuts" />
```

The canonical tags are the issue here so best fix them up.

Here's Google's info on the subject. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Hope this helps.

William